# "that" instead of "stating that"

Tags: relative-clauses

I wrote:

> Therefore, we reject the null hypothesis **stating** that these variable are independent.

The null hypothesis is "The variables X and Y are independent". Using a hypothesis testing we decided to reject this hypothesis. Could I write the sentence above as:

> Therefore, we reject the null hypothesis that these variable are independent.

In general, can I use "that" instead of "which states that" or "which says that" or "which shows that" ...?

Comment: Whoa there. *Stating* and *which states* mean two different things, and vastly change your first quote section! *Which states* explains what the null hypothesis is, but *stating* indicates that you *state something* while rejecting the null hypothesis. The explanation below makes it clear you mean *which states* and that your second quote would be accurate for what you really want to say.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may say

> Thus, we reject the null hypothesis that these variables are independent.

A hypothesis is a type of statement so we can dispense with "stating" or "that states" as redundant.